# CreateObject fails for Com visible dll

Tags: .net, asp-classic, createobject

I have a com visible dll that I am trying to call from classic ASP.  I have successfully registered it using regasm and I'm still hitting the following error.

0x80131600 - Server object: 006~ASP 0177~Server.CreateObject Failed~80131600

the application works fine on many other machines so there is something environmental causing a problem on my box.  Here is the code I'm using

set oMyVariable = Server.CreateObject("components.MyComponent")

- I've tried removing 'Server.', same problem
- I've looked at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c450276-44bc-40d3-a698-3da1e640f791/throwing-exception-from-comvisible-class-constuctor but this doesn't help
- I've tried resetting the permissions to the folder where the dll is located, same problem
- I've tried resetting the registry permissions for the type - same problem

I'm at a loss on what could be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was caused by one of the components referenced by MyComponent having an entry messed up in the registry.  Was extremely difficult to track down and understand why it happened.